# 'Sarah and Jane's philosophy of life' or 'Sarah's and Jane's philosophy of life'?

Tags: compound-possessives

I am not sure. I want to say 'Jane's and Sarah's etc' but the 'etc' being both's, is it written 'Jane and Sarah's etc.'? And is this always the case or are there exceptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First start by referring to [the linked question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x) (possible duplicate).

The singular use of *philosophy* suggests that this is a shared (or joint) possession and only the final possessive inflection should be used.  If they are actually distinct philosophies, then you should show the possessive inflection for both, but *philosophy* should be pluralized, also.