# Bill's friends' car - where to place the apostrophes

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Do I need two apostrophes or only one?

Where should I place the apostrophe if I need only one in the following sentence:

> I borrowed Bill's friends' car

Comment: You need two apostrophes - Bill's friend's car.

Comment: who does the car belong to, Bill's friend or Bill's friends? or indeed is it Bill's car that he uses to visit his friend(s) with?

Comment: To add to @JonMarkPerry's comment, there's a third (rather unlikely) option: Bill keeps a car for use by friends, something referred to as a "pool car" or "friends car" in the UK. In your sentence you might borrow that car: *I borrowed Bill's friends car*.

Comment: Related: [“Nikki's and Alice's X” vs. “Nikki and Alice's X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x) I know this OP has been asked before but I can't find its duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked in the archives  but I couldn't find an older question that answers the OP's one, the sentence requires two apostrophes because we're speaking about two different nouns belonging to *two* different owners. The first noun is "friend" while the second is "car". 
Presumably, in everyday life, the car, *a friend's car*, belongs to a single friend of Bill = Bill's friend.

> 1. I borrowed Bill’**s** frien**d's** car

If the car belonged to more than one friend (unlikely, but not impossible...) then the apostrophe must immediately follow the suffix denoting plurality, i.e., **-s**, as so:

> ... Bill’**s** frien**ds'** car

However, in the real world, I would rephrase the sentence because placing two possessive nouns, one after the other, looks and sounds a bit awkward to me. My solution would be:

> 1. I **borrowed** this car **off** Bill's friend

The "off", as used above, is considered nonstandard in English. I don't know if American English speakers use this particular structure, but I find it very useful and very natural. I would not recommend using this in formal writing or in an English language exam, but it's fine in speech.

[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/borrow) says

> uk non-standard
>   *Can I **borrow** £100 **off** you until next week?*

A more formal construction would be

> 2. I borrowed this car from **a friend of** Bill's
> 3. The car belongs to **a friend of** Bill's
> 4. I borrowed the car from Bill'**s** friend