# Apostrophe with conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, apostrophe

Should we say:

> I am a great fan of Shakespear's and Enid Byton's writing

or

> I am a great fan of Shakespeare and Enid Blyton's writing

Comment: I suggest instead that you  write, "I am a great fan of Shakespeare and the writings of Enid Blyton."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Nikki's and Alice's X" vs. "Nikki and Alice's X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x) (Nikki and Alice obviously predating Shakespeare and Enid Blyton.) This hinges on joint vs individual possession (or, as here, broader ownership, and grading to mere association).

Comment: Yes, thank you, @Edwin Ashworth!