# How to use apostrophe properly in this sentence?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

There's a person named *Khushwant Singh* in a story. He and his grandmother are friends.

There's a question asked in my book: What is the 'turning point' in the story?

And my answer begins something like this:

'The turning point' in the lesson refers to the turning point in Khushwant Singh's and his grandmother's friendship.

Now here's where I get confused. Did I use the apostrophes properly? If I didn't use it properly, how should I use it properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x

Comment: In this case, their friendship is one item, similar to a single cookie called a black and white cookie. So, one apostrophe is enough for me. But I would reword to "turning point in the friendship *between* Singh and his grandmother."

Comment: @YosefBaskin Does changing the word to *between* change the meaning of the sentence or does it remain the same?

Comment: The word *between* connects their friendship as one bridge. No change in meaning from the original versions.