# possessive case with plural

Tags: possessives, grammatical-case

How can I use the possessive case with many objects " *s' "?
2*Jane and 2*Mary 2*room;

it is right? :

girls’ book**s**

Jane and Maries’ room**s**

the childr*e*n’s toy**s**

the workm*e*n’s tool**s**

Peter and Helens’ flat**s** **are** large

**10*Jane and 10*Mary 10*room;**

Jane and Maries’ room**s**
or/and
Janes' and Maries’ room**s**

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x

Comment: The plural of Mary is usually not Maries

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Nikki's and Alice's X" vs. "Nikki and Alice's X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x)

Comment: Anyway, _Mary_ doesn't need to be plural (unless there are two girls with the same name).

Comment: Do Jane and Mary (or Marie, or the several Maries) have one room each or several rooms which they both, or all, occupy? The same applies to Peter and Helen, are they a couple with multiple flats (or perhaps partners in a property rental business) or do they have one flat each?

Comment: JaneS (2 pc.) & MaryS (2 pc.) have roomS (2pc.) "Janes' and Maries’ rooms"