# “Her and her brother's” or “Hers and her brother's”

Tags: grammar

> (1) Her and her brother's gifts are under the tree.

> (2) Hers and her brother's gifts are under the tree.

Something tells me the (1) is correct, but (2) looks/sounds better to me.

Searched internet for help but found little.

And what about something like this? "She heard hers and Debbie’s names spoken clearly and, touchingly, with warmth." Do I remove the S on hers, or the S on names perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Nikki's and Alice's X" vs. "Nikki and Alice's X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x)

Comment: I wish it did. I still like example 2 better. Is that correct?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: _Her_ gifts are under the tree. Mentioning the brother as well doesn't alter the basic grammar.

Comment: The gifts are hers. The gifts are his. Her gifts are under the tree. His gifts are under the tree.

Comment: ***Jack and Jill's parents are here*** is potentially ambiguous, unless we know whether Jack & Jill definitely are or aren't siblings (there could be  one ***or*** two sets of parents). But I see no scope for ambiguity in ***Jack's and Jill's parents are here*** - to me, that simply wouldn't be idiomatically valid if they were siblings who shared the same two parents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) Her brother's and her ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, that's the better choice of duplicate. Not only because it's more relevant to the exact question here - it's also got one of those truly stellar answers from Kosmonaut, who sadly rarely contributes these days.

Comment: You're full of puns today, FF. @Kosmonaut, try to keep him busy stellar-answer-gazing!

Comment: I'm still confused. Sorry. Is example 1 or example 2 correctly worded?