# How to write "my and my friend's" to refer to same object ("my and my friend's toys")

Tags: phrases, possessives

How would I best phrase "my and my friend's toys"? The sentence in mind is quite descriptive of the toys and I would thus not like to repeat the adjectives twice (ex. "my bright, colorful toys and my friend's bright, colorful toys") if possible.

Full sentence and preceding sentence:

> I don't remember many of my toys. My and my friend's bright, colorful toys were frequently used as bargaining tools within familial environments, trying to encourage us to learn better ways to align our actions with their desires, to rare success.

Comment: Can you provide the full sentence or further context?

Comment: @alphabet - edited question for this

Comment: "The bright, colourful toys belonging to me and my friend..."

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x) and search using the tags because I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Nice question!  It's not 'wrong' as you have written it but, to avoid the close repitition of '*my*', you might prefer to say "*...my friend's and my bright, colorful toys were frequently used...*"

Comment: No, it's not wrong, but it's clumsy and destroys parallel structures, so it's avoided. Use _my friend and I_ early and then use _our_ as the possessive later.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the following:

> Our toys

> The toys belonging to both of us

> Our shared toys

> The toys we both possess

> The toys that belong to both of us

Comment: I don't think this works. I've added a sample of the sentences in question. I haven't introduced who the "our" refers to before this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example, rewriting the sentence works better as "I don't remember many of my toys. My friend and I each frequently used our bright, colourful toys as bargaining tools". The word "each" would be important to suggest they were not shared toys (although it possibly could still be misunderstood).

Answer (score 0):

"My and my friend's shared collection of bright and colorful toys" or "Our joint collection of bright and colorful toys" could be used to describe the toys belonging to both you and your friend without repeating the adjectives.